# Installer project with 2 primary output files

Tags: visual-studio

I created a multi tiered .net application which includes the Client and the Server projects. I want to create setup for it so that during installation, the user may choose to install the Server or the Client (by selecting appropriate radio button). I created an interface for the selection but it always installs both the Server and the Client no matter which option I select. How can I choose to install only Server or Client based on the selection?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Condition property on the appropriate output files based on the radio button selections.  Here is an article that shows step-by-step instructions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x23561f(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Assume that you have 'ServerInstall' and 'ClientInstall' (let those be simplified terms for file systems etc. corresponding to each version you want to install). Now, having a RadioButton(2) dialog box in your installation, you gain access to a condition (in the example - BUTTON2), which has to be set in each file to value 1 or 2 depending whether the file is specific for client or server.